# How to trigger an SVG animation on scroll?

Tags: javascript, svg, onscroll

So I've finally cracked SVG animations (totally through cheating) and like most sites that use them if they're halfway down the page they begin automatically and you miss it, so how is it possible to trigger the animation on scroll to that div container?

Any help would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`beginElement()` function to starts animations manually.

for this to work, you have to set the `begin` attribute of `animate` element to `indefinite`

a simple example would be something like

```
window.onscroll = function(){
  var anime= document.getElementsByTagName('animate')[0];
  // check for the amount of scroll
  anime.beginElement();
}
```

You could also make use of `beginElementAt()`

read more about [svg Animation Timing Control](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#InterfaceElementTimeControl)

*side note: Can't be more accurate since you haven't shared much info or code samples, and not sure what you meant by 'cheating'*

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and mess around with that, I'm pretty new at JS so will see what happens... my current site is www.oliverfreeman.com/v2    the brand section is the section with the SVG, what I meant by cheating is that there is a site where you can just drop your illustrator file into the site and it automatically animates it for you